# Bootstrap Datetimepicker on select event

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

**How do I access a js function exampleFunction() when date is selected?** I want to pass the date value there.

text_field_tag for datetimepicker (haml):

```
= text_field_tag 'start_day', class: 'datepick'
```

Javascript:

```
$(".datepick").datetimepicker({
  timepicker: false,
  format: 'd/m/Y',
  closeOnDateSelect: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the plugin you are using then it would be Like this.

```
$(".datepick").datetimepicker({
  onChangeDateTime:exampleFunction
});
function exampleFunction(){
  console.log("Date Selected")
}
```

For full option list Reference:
http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this by using below given code:

```
$("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
     console.log(e.date);
});
```

I your case, it should be :

```
$(".datepick").on("dp.change",function(e){ exampleFunction(e.date)  });
```

Remember this will call the example function on change in value of each datetimepicker, since you used class.

**Reference URL**: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: What does 'e' mean in function(e)?

Comment: Catch e in your console and check it out yourself! using console.log(e).

Comment: should be the perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".datepick").datetimepicker({
  timepicker: false,
  format: 'd/m/Y',
  closeOnDateSelect: true
}).on('dp.change', function (ev) {
    exampleFunction() ;//your function call
});
```

Comment: What does 'ev' mean?

Comment: variable from which you can get selected date detail.It is just variable name to handle callback functionality

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
$(".datepick").datetimepicker({
  format: 'd/m/Y',
}).on('select', function (e) {
        console.log('on select event');
    });
```