# Based on datetime pick calculate new dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Based on select in datetimepicker I would like to set three dates. First is *selected date* + 28days, second *selected date* + 56days and third *selected date* + 84days. If user set a new date, script must do new calculation and set the this new dates in fields: *datummeritve2, datummeritve3, datummeritve5*.

I've seen some similar questions, but mostly it's not used *datetimepicker* and also with the answers there were writen I was not able to make it work.

In short.. When user picks a date, other fields must be filled with new calculated dates.

This is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class='input-group date' id=''>
        <p><span class="napis">Pick a date</span></p>
        <input style="width: 280px;" type='text' class="form-control" id="datummeritve1" name="datummeritve1" placeholder="Datum meritve"  value=""/>
    </div>
</div>


<input style="width: 280px;" type='text' class="form-control" id="datummeritve2" name="datummeritve2" placeholder="Datum meritve"  value=""/>

<input style="width: 280px;" type='text' class="form-control" id="datummeritve3" name="datummeritve3" placeholder="Datum meritve"  value=""/>

<input style="width: 280px;" type='text' class="form-control" id="datummeritve4" name="datummeritve4" placeholder="Datum meritve"  value=""/>
```

**JS**

```
$('#datummeritve1').datetimepicker({
    onShow: function(ct){
        this.setOptions({
            minDate: new Date()
        });
    },
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    formatDate: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    datepicker: true,
    timepicker: false   
});
```

Comment: first you need to handle the `onselected` event of datetimepicker where you get the selected date, then use that date to add the days you need and set the `input` values to those dates. [Example of `onselected` event handling] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127937/bootstrap-datetimepicker-on-select-event)

Comment: onchange also must be taken into account..

I know approximately what is required, I have a problem with the syntax, because I'm not so familiar with jQuery javascript code..

Comment: google :) and u shall see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my answer you have to include moment.js as well. You also have to set "disabled" for the input fields #datummeritve2, #datummeritve3 and #datummeritve4. NOTE: The user still can easily change them. You also have to check the dateDifference serverside

```
  // Init the non clickable 
  $('#datummeritve2, #datummeritve3, #datummeritve4').datetimepicker({
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      locale:moment.locale('de-at'),
      format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
      ignoreReadonly:false 
  });

  // Init the main clickable
  $('#datummeritve1').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    locale:moment.locale('de-at'),
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    ignoreReadonly:false 
  }).on("dp.change",function(e){

    // Fetch the current date
    var date28 = new Date(moment($("#datummeritve1").val(), "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").toDate());
    var date56 = new Date(moment($("#datummeritve1").val(), "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").toDate());
    var date84 = new Date(moment($("#datummeritve1").val(), "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").toDate());    

    // Add the days to the dates
    date28.setDate(date28.getDate()+28);
    date56.setDate(date56.getDate()+56);
    date84.setDate(date84.getDate()+84);

    // set it 
    $("#datummeritve2").data("DateTimePicker").date(date28);
    $("#datummeritve3").data("DateTimePicker").date(date56);
    $("#datummeritve4").data("DateTimePicker").date(date84);

  });
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rwj2Lmh2/1/

Comment: Tnx for reply. I've tried this code and nothing happend. I also DL and inlude moment.js file (https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js) - I assume that this is correct.. What did I miss?! One more thing.. The new dates can be put in text fields.. Users should not have the possibility to change the value.. Just to read it. Later.. this form will be submitted and data will be saved in database (mysql).

Comment: I've put alert inside of function $("#datummeritve1").on("dp.change",function(e){.. and nothing.. I've change it to this: 

$("#datummeritve1").change(function(){
   var newEnd = new Date(moment($("#datummeritve1").val(), "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").toDate());
   newEnd.setHours(newEnd.getDate()+28);


   $("#datummeritve2").val(newEnd);
  });

Now I get in input "Sat Feb 11 2017 14:00:00 GMT+0100" which is not correct..

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work (at least I think I did ;))..

Here is my code now. Maybe it can help someone..

**JS**

```
$('#datummeritve1').datetimepicker({
    onShow: function(ct){
        this.setOptions({
            minDate: new Date()
            });
        },
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        formatDate: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        datepicker: true,
        timepicker: false   
});

$("#datummeritve1").change(function(){

    var newEnd = new Date(moment($("#datummeritve1").val(), "DD.MM.YYYY").toDate());
    newEnd.setDate(newEnd.getDate()+28);            
    $("#datummeritve2").val(moment(newEnd).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));

    newEnd.setDate(newEnd.getDate()+28);
    $("#datummeritve3").val(moment(newEnd).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));

    newEnd.setDate(newEnd.getDate()+28);
    $("#datummeritve4").val(moment(newEnd).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <input style="width: 280px;" type='text' class="form-control" id="datummeritve1" name="datummeritve1" placeholder="Datum meritve"  value=""/>

    <input readonly style="width: 280px;" name="datummeritve2" type="text" id="datummeritve2" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="">
    <input readonly style="width: 280px;" name="datummeritve3" type="text" id="datummeritve3" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="">
    <input readonly style="width: 280px;" name="datummeritve4" type="text" id="datummeritve4" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="">
```

**Summary:** Based on selection of the date (datetimepicker). Text fields (readonly) are filled with generated dates.